# Causality studies between porn use and masturbation frequency?

Tags: sexuality, addiction

Research into purported porn addiction (which goes by many names, PPU = problematic porn use being one) identified strong correlation between porn use and frequency of masturbation. [For instance](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28409565):

[image]

Is there any research exploring causality between these two? In other words, do people who watch more porn do so because they want to mastubate more often, or is it the other way around, i.e. watching more porn turns people on so they masturabate more often? (Or in more proposed-pathological terms, is porn addiction just a banal version of hypersexuality or is it an addiction on its own causing hypersexuality?)